# Existe uma diferença entre uma árvore binária perfeita e uma árvore binária balanceada?

Tags: terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária, ciência-da-computação

Como posso compreender uma árvore binária balanceada e uma árvore binária perfeita?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, como o nome diz uma árvore binária perfeita tem todos seus nós uniformes, não tendo nenhum desbalanceamento, portanto sempre está ligados a 2 nós (exceto o último que evidentemente pode ter um só). Ela é perfeitamente balanceada. É muito trabalhoso para o algoritmo manter isto e não costuma valer o esforço. Algo assim:

```
         5 
       /   \
     3       7
   /   \   /   \
  1     4 6     8
```

A árvore binária balanceada admite um desbalanceamento de 1 nível. Pode ser assim:

```
         5 
       /   \
     3       7
   /   \       \
  1     4       8
```

Mais um nível abaixo do 8 não seria admitido e a árvore ficaria desbalanceada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Toda arvore perfeita é balanceada então?

Comment: Na sua arvore balanceada. Se retirar a folha 1 ela continua balanceada?

Comment: Sim, perfeitamente balanceada. Neste caso tirar continuaria balanceada, mas colocar depende do lugar, justamente aí em algum caso exigiria um rebalanceamento. A perfeita exige rebalanceamento em muitas situações porque só o último nível pode ficar desbalanceado (não tem como exigir que todos sejam).

Answer (score 3):

Um adendo em relação a resposta do Maniero, é que uma árvore binária perfeita é sempre balanceada mas o contrário não é verdade. A principal característica de uma árvore perfeita é ter o número total de nós pertencente ao conjunto {1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, ..., 2^(n+1)-1}, sendo n altura, assim todas as folhas estarão no mesmo nível. 
Uma árvore balanceada leva em conta o fato de balanceamento de cada nó, que pode assumir -1,0 ou 1, para obter o fator de um nó você faz a diferença da altura esquerda e direita desse nó.( Esse fator pode ser tratado como modular também pode-se admitir em alguns apenas 0 ou 1 apenas).

Recomendo esse site: https://sites.google.com/site/esdicapsi/estruturas-dinamicas/arvores-binarias

Esse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkF76cOgtMQ&list=PLxI8Can9yAHf8k8LrUePyj0y3lLpigGcl&index=21